# C LibCurl file upload to ruby on rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, curl, libcurl

I am trying to upload text files to a ruby on rails server. I was successful at uploading the file through CLI:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode data@/etc/filepath/ www.example.com/path
```

Now, trying with libCurl through C:

```
        FILE *fd;
        fd = fopen(file_path, "rb");
        if (!fd)
            return -1;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
    }
```

Any ideas why running through CLI would work, but libCurl does not? Am I missing some curl options or does my server require alternate configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` **or** `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` basically. Do you want to provide the data as a string or read it from the file?

You also don't want **both** `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_UPLOAD`, as the later implies `PUT`.